# Switch between Python 2.7 and 2.6

Tags: python, linux, fedora

Im using virtualenv on Fedora 16 and Ive just created a new virtualenv so that I can build an environment to run a piece of software.

I have another virtualenv which I managed to set up to use Python 2.6, but I cant remember how. I remember it was relatively simple. Something like `yum install Python2.6` but no matter how much I search I cant find an answer on how to do this.

My root is using Python 2.7, all I need is for the virtualenv to use 2.6. Thats all. If I have to create a new one thats fine. There is no 2.6 installed in my root but it does seem to be in the bin of my other virtualenv

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If creating a new environment is an option, than you can just create it like this:

```
virtualenv -p path_to_python26_executable desired_path_to_new_virtualenv
```

Here is the quote from `virtualenv --help`:

```
-p PYTHON_EXE, --python=PYTHON_EXE
                    The Python interpreter to use, e.g.,
                    --python=python2.5 will use the python2.5 interpreter
                    to create the new environment.  The default is the
                    interpreter that virtualenv was installed with
                    (/usr/bin/python)
```

Comment: This actually worked, what I need to know now is... how do I switch my Pylons version!?

Comment: If you have `pip` installed, than `pip uninstall Pylons` and than `pip install Pylons==desired_version`. If you don't have `pip` installed, then you might want to install it or to wipe the current installation of Pylons out manually (it must be somewhere in site-packages directory). By the way, have you considered installing Python 2.6, say, from sources? Then you'll be able to do anything you want with your virtualenvs.